# Is it possible to build index for labels in vertex

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to create index for vertex label.Vertex is created as below

```
val v0 = graph + "A"
```

Each of my gremlin query based on vertex label.Getting below warining message

**WARN  c.t.t.g.transaction.StandardTitanTx - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(~label = 301)]. For better performance, use indexes**

Project used Titan + cassandra(Storage Backend), below are the SBT dependencies used,

```
"com.michaelpollmeier" %% "gremlin-scala" % "3.0.2-incubating.2",
"com.thinkaurelius.titan" % "titan-core" % "1.0.0",
"com.thinkaurelius.titan" % "titan-cassandra" % "1.0.0",
"com.netflix.astyanax" % "astyanax-cassandra" % "3.9.0",
"com.netflix.astyanax" % "astyanax-core" % "3.9.0",
"com.netflix.astyanax" % "astyanax-thrift" % "3.9.0"
```

Created index as below,

```
mgmt.makePropertyKey("endpoint").dataType(classOf[String]).m‌​ake(); 

mgmt.buildIndex("endpoint",classOf[Vertex]).addKey(name1).un‌​ique().buildComposit‌​eIndex() 

mgmt.commit() 

graph.tx().commit()
```

Getting this error

com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.SchemaViolationException: Adding this property for key [~T$SchemaName] and value [rtendpoint] violates a uniqueness constraint [SystemIndex#~T$SchemaName]

Comment: Rather than continuously comment you should edit your own question with these additional pieces of information. It makes your problem easier to understand and you will likely get more help form the community.

Comment: Removed the comments and updated the latest problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala):

> you can always easily access the underlying Gremlin-Java objects if needed, e.g. to access graph db specifics things like indexes

So I assume the process should be the same as the one defined [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html).

Based on that assumption, first of all, you apply indexing to properties not to labels. It is however a good idea to create you graph schema in advanced of loading data. That being said you probably want to do the following:

```
TitanManagement management = graph.openManagement();
```

**1. Define Your Vertex Labels**

This can be done with:

```
VertexLabel foundLabel = management.getVertexLabel("A");
if(foundLabel == null)
    management.makeVertexLabel("A").make();
```

**2. Define your properties**

This lets Titan know which properties it can expect to index:

```
if (management.getPropertyKey("ID") == null) {
    management.makePropertyKey("ID").dataType(String.class).make();
}
```

**3. Define the Indexed Properties**

When you index a property then your traversals against those properties will be much faster:

```
TitanIndex index = management.getGraphIndex("byID");
if(index == null) {
    PropertyKey key = management.getPropertyKey("ID");
    TitanManagement.IndexBuilder indexBuilder = management.buildIndex("byID", Vertex.class).addKey(key);
    if (isUnique) //Do you want the property to be unique ?
        indexBuilder.unique();
    indexBuilder.buildCompositeIndex();
}
```

Comment: Teixeria Thank you very much for the answer. I am having few doubts in that. **1. Define Your Vertex Labels** Why we need to do that ? **2**. When we create vertex we need to set this property(ID) with some value is it and traverse using ID instead of using `hasLabel` Am i right ?

Comment: Defining it in advance is typically good practice. It's not recommended but sometimes when you have a lot of indexing and a lot of properties, if you try to create a new label on the fly, Titan will complain that it is a SchemaViolation.

As for your 2nd question, yes that is correct. To use indexing you should be traversing across properties, not labels. I just use `ID` as en example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have modified my quries as below `graph.V().has(ID,A).out().label().toList()` . Now the WARN messages are not coming.

Comment: After changing to has(ID,A) some existing queries stopped working, **Existing :** `graph.traversal().V()
      .hasLabel(A).outE("interference").as("x").otherV()
      .hasLabel(B).select("x").property("weight",10).iterate();` Its not able to resolve `property("weight",10).iterate();`